# Disposal of methanol solution

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Can I add a 4 L bottle of methanol solution with 0.1% formic acid into a drum containing non-halogenated waste?

Comment: Immediately contact your local ES&H personnel. They should know all appropriate local/regional/country laws on disposal. Note that mixing acids and organics is generally not a good thing, and there may be further issues with whatever else is in the drum. Get professional advice right now, and not from random folks on the internet.

Comment: Seems you're asking rather if it's a good idea, which may or may not be the case and we can't know it in general, as it depends on situation. Asking this on internet probably is _not_ good idea. That being said, much worse things go to drain around the world, and you seem to worry too much.

Comment: Jon is right, while I know that I am a nice person and a decent chemist. You do not know the people here in person. I would trust your local health, safety and environmental persons more than random folk off the internet.

Comment: This is a very fact specific question. Dependent on the contents of the non-halogenated waste and what waste streams your facility has established.

Comment: If there is nothing else (bad) in your solution, dilute it in 10x the amount of water and pour it down the drain. I mean definitely ask the responsible people, but that's what I'd say if I was responsible. 0.1% of formic acid is irrelevant, methanol is harmless unless you drink or put your hand in it.

Comment: @Karl - that would be illegal where I am.